# How to use vi to edit a command in terminal on Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

When typing a very long command, I'd like to first edit the command in a text editor(e.g. vi) then execute in case of typos. Is there a way to edit the command directly in a terminal and run instead of invoke vi by typing vi then type the command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using bash, try the `edit-and-execute-command` command. By default, this is assigned to `Ctrl-x Ctrl-e` (type ctrl-x, then ctrl-e).

This should open whatever editor is specified in your environment. Whatever is in the buffer when you exit will execute in the shell - including multiple-line commands.

Comment: If bash editing mode is vi, this may not work. See `bind -P` to check if  `edit-and-execute-command` is bound at all and if not, one can assign it (see `help bind`). A good blog post on GNU Readline and bash: https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vi-mode-in-bash/

Comment: @toraritte in vi mode, `<Esc>v` does it

Answer (score 11):

You can by setting vi editing mode. If you are using bash, you can enter the following or put it in your [shell configuration files](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html):

```
set -o vi
```

You can then, just like in vi use command mode and insert mode.

When a command is already on the line (called up by pressing the up arrow key, `CTRL-R`, `fzf`, etc.),  a useful command is `v` when in normal mode on the shell, because it will start the default editor to edit the command.

A cheat sheet from [this gist](https://github.com/pkrumins/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/blob/master/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt):

```
.---------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|                                                                           |
|                          Readline VI Editing Mode                         |
|                     Default Keyboard Shortcuts for Bash                   |
|                               Cheat Sheet                                 |
|                                                                           |
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------'
| Peteris Krumins (peter@catonmat.net), 2008.01.08                          |
| http://www.catonmat.net  -  good coders code, great reuse                 |
|                                                                           |
| Released under the GNU Free Document License                              |
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------'

 ======================== Keyboard Shortcut Summary ========================

.--------------.------------------------------------------------------------.
|              |                                                            |
| Shortcut     | Description                                                |
|              |                                                            |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Switching to COMMAND Mode:                                                |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| ESC          | Switch to command mode.                                    |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Commands for Entering INPUT Mode:                                         |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| i            | Insert before cursor.                                      |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| a            | Insert after cursor.                                       |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| I            | Insert at the beginning of line.                           |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| A            | Insert at the end of line.                                 |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| c<mov. comm> | Change text of a movement command <mov. comm> (see below). |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| C            | Change text to the end of line (equivalent to c$).         |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| cc or S      | Change current line (equivalent to 0c$).                   |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| s            | Delete a single character under the cursor and enter input |
|              | mode (equivalent to c[SPACE]).                             |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| r            | Replaces a single character under the cursor (without      |
|              | leaving command mode).                                     |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| R            | Replaces characters under cursor.                          |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| v            | Edit (and execute) the current command in the text editor. |
|              | (an editor defined in $VISUAL or $EDITOR variables, or vi  |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Basic Movement Commands (in command mode):                                |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| h            | Move one character right.                                  |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| l            | Move one character left.                                   |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| w            | Move one word or token right.                              |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| b            | Move one word or token left.                               |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| W            | Move one non-blank word right.                             |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| B            | Move one non-blank word left.                              |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| e            | Move to the end of the current word.                       |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| E            | Move to the end of the current non-blank word.             |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| 0            | Move to the beginning of line                              |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| ^            | Move to the first non-blank character of line.             |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| $            | Move to the end of line.                                   |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| %            | Move to the corresponding opening/closing bracket.         |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Character Finding Commands (these are also Movement Commands):            |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| fc           | Move right to the next occurance of char c.                |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| Fc           | Move left to the previous occurance of c.                  |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| tc           | Move right to the next occurance of c, then one char       |
|              | backward.                                                  |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| Tc           | Move left to the previous occurance of c, then one char    |
|              | forward.                                                   |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| ;            | Redo the last character finding command.                   |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| ,            | Redo the last character finding command in opposite        |
|              | direction.                                                 |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| |            | Move to the n-th column (you may specify the argument n by |
|              | typing it on number keys, for example, 20|)                |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Deletion Commands:                                                        |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| x            | Delete a single character under the cursor.                |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| X            | Delete a character before the cursor.                      |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| d<mov. comm> | Delete text of a movement command <mov. comm> (see above). |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| D            | Delete to the end of the line (equivalent to d$).          |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| dd           | Delete current line (equivalent to 0d$).                   |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| CTRL-w       | Delete the previous word.                                  |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| CTRL-u       | Delete from the cursor to the beginning of line.           |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Undo, Redo and Copy/Paste Commands:                                       |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| u            | Undo previous text modification.                           |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| U            | Undo all previous text modifications.                      |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| .            | Redo the last text modification.                           |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| y<mov. comm> | Yank a movement into buffer (copy).                        |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| yy           | Yank the whole line.                                       |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| p            | Insert the yanked text at the cursor.                      |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| P            | Insert the yanked text before the cursor.                  |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Commands for Command History:                                             |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| k            | Move backward one command in history.                      |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| j            | Move forward one command in history.                       |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| G            | Move to history line N (for example, 15G).                 |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| /string or   | Search history backward for a command matching string.     |
| CTRL-r       |                                                            |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| ?string or   | Search history forward for a command matching string.      |
| CTRL-s       | (Note that on most machines Ctrl-s STOPS the terminal      |
|              | output, change it with `stty' (Ctrl-q to resume)).         |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| n            | Repeat search in the same direction as previous.           |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| N            | Repeat search in the opposite direction as previous.       |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Completion commands:                                                      |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| TAB or = or  | List all possible completions.                             |
| CTRL-i       |                                                            |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| *            | Insert all possible completions.                           |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'
| Miscellaneous commands:                                                   |
'--------------.------------------------------------------------------------'
| ~            | Invert case of the character under cursor and move a       |
|              | character right.                                           |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| #            | Prepend '#' (comment character) to the line and send it to |
|              | the history.                                               |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| _            | Inserts the n-th word of the previous command in the       |
|              | current line.                                              |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| 0, 1, 2, ... | Sets the numeric argument.                                 |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| CTRL-v       | Insert a character literally (quoted insert).              |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| CTRL-r       | Transpose (exchange) two characters.                       |
'--------------'------------------------------------------------------------'


 ===========================================================================

.---------------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Peteris Krumins (peter@catonmat.net), 2008.01.08.                         |
| http://www.catonmat.net  -  good coders code, great reuse                 | 
|                                                                           |
| Released under the GNU Free Document License                              |
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `zsh` the shell-command is called `edit-command-line`. It is not bound by default, so add something like this to your configuration:

```
bindkey "^X^E" edit-command-line
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+e</kbd> will work the same way as in `bash` except that the command is not executed before <kbd>Return</kbd> is struck.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the **`fc`** ("fix command") shell built-in?<sup>1</sup>

By default, it opens the very last command in your editor, but you can discard that and replace it with whatever you wish, and it gets executed on exit. See `help fc`.

Idea suggested by Tom Ryder in his blog post, [Vi mode in Bash](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vi-mode-in-bash/).

---

(1) Available in fish, zsh, bash, dash, but probably in others as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the fish shell instead of bash you can open the current command in an editor with:

`Alt-v` (which uses the editor set in the VISUAL environment variable)

`Alt-e` (which uses the editor set in the EDITOR environment variable)