# How to edit a command output and execute it?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, text-editor

[It's possible edit a command in standard editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655587/how-to-use-vi-to-edit-a-command-in-terminal-on-linux?s=1%7C2.8474)

But I don't found how to edit OUTPUT of command and execute it in command line.
By example, if I type:

> remake

I obtain:

> El programa «remake» no está instalado. Puede instalarlo escribiendo:
>   sudo apt-get install remake

I like remove de first line, and execute the second one.

This is special case because output is fron stderr instead of stout.

But in other cases is usefull edit output, add  command and execute it.

Comment: A question with very similar example.
But Id like a generic answer.
Many thank for all.

Comment: Its possible send output to Vim. Example `ls |vim -`
But how to exec text inside vim like in this trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655587/how-to-use-vi-to-edit-a-command-in-terminal-on-linux?s=1%7C2.8474

Comment: An answer, but i don't know if elegant. Example: ls|vipe | eval `more`. Edit inside vim. By example cat text.txt, and :wq
Works, but I have to install vipe, but before this ctrl-x ctrl-e yet works. I think have to exit a solution without install vipe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`.

I would do it like this:

```
remake 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -v -l -i "El programa «remake» no está in stalado."
```

Or just this:

```
remake 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -l -i "Puede instalarlo escribiendo: sudo apt-get install remake"
```

| is a pipe, it sends command output to grep (which then filters the output) and prints stdout.

In this case, we redirect stderr (2) input to stdout (&1) to `/dev/null`, then we filter it with grep.

Comment: Thank for answer.
Don't work for me.
But i fixed it. 
`eval  $(remake 2>/dev/stdout  | grep "sudo")`
But I need a generic solution. Capture output, edit by hand, and execute it.

Comment: Note this doesn't execute the result.

Comment: Fixed it, my bad, i forgot about stderr.

Answer (score 0):

I think once you got the output, it's too late - Output is not stored anywhere.
If you know your command will issue an error, you could do :

```
`remake 2>&1 | sed -n '2 p'`
```

which would execute the second line of error output (that is,  sudo apt-get install remake).

Explanation :

```
remake
2>&1 : redirects stderr to stdout
| sed -n '2 p' : only print the second line
backquotes (``) : executes the command
```

But that means you know your program is not installed, so better write directly :

```
sudo apt-get install remake
```

I would rather try to intercept the "program not installed, install it " behaviour, so as to ask "install it [y/n]".

But maybe you don't know a simple trick : you can copy & paste the command just by selecting the command part (sudo apt-get install ...) with the mouse, and clicking with right or middle button (depending on the terminal emulator you use).

Comment: I go to instal gpm and try it. Thanks pierre.
Remake is only a example.
Id like a solution for any output. The output maybe don't have any command and it's added in vi, by example.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your comment, the answer will depend on what you want to do with your output.

First of all, you have to save the output;

Extensively, you can save it in a temp file you open in vi :

```
TMPFILE=`mktemp`
my-command > $TMPFILE
vi $TMPFILE
// do whatever you want with $TMPFILE :
// source $TMPFILE // to execute it
```

which can be stored as a function

```
function editrun() {
    TMPFILE=`mktemp`
    "$@" > $TMPFILE 2>&1 # run the command, redirects stdout to $TMPFILE, and also stderr
    vi $TMPFILE
    source $TMPFILE
}
```

Then you can call

```
editrun my shell command with arguments
```

For example :

```
editrun echo ls -al
```

To get and run the command line, I used "$@". This should work in almost any situation; however, it should be possible to get the full bash command-line with some special bash variables.